# Looking for a regular expression to extract http valid URIs from a file?

Tags: regex, sed

I'm looking for a regular expression which can extract http URIs from a file (arbitrary text). Note that text can have word "http" but that word might or might not represent a valid URI address.

UPDATE: I understand that HTML is a context free grammar while RegEx is a regular expression but are URIs are just patterns (regular expression). Or not?

Comment: I would just like to point out, that using regex when they are not appropriate [may cause madness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).  What you are asking for is not possible with 100% accuracy.

Comment: I understand that HTML is a context free grammar while RegEx is a regular expression but are URIs are just patterns (regular expression). Or not?

Comment: @Zoredache, what are you *crazy* ​‽ You don’t do regex for fun?

Comment: Provided that you're constraining yourself to well-formed URLs, including protocol prefixes (preferably constrained to a specific set of protocols), regexes can do a pretty good job with this (and many sites use them for just that). But 100% accuracy is still not possible because of things like "`Found this at http://somesite.com/foo.`", where neither regex nor context-free grammars can reliably determine whether the final "." should be part of the URL or not and the link is unlikely to work if the parser gets it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It's harder than you think and no regular-expression is lightly to catch them all.
Consider urls like this

> http://www.google.com/search?q=good+url+regex&rls=com.microsoft:*&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&startIndex=&startPage=1
>
> ftp://joe:password@ftp.filetransferprotocal.com
>
> google.ru
>
> https://some-url.com?query=&name=joe?filter=*.*#some_anchor

Here is a good short article on the subject [A good url regular expression?](http://flanders.co.nz/2009/11/08/a-good-url-regular-expression-repost/)

```
^(?#Protocol)(?:(?:ht|f)tp(?:s?)\:\/\/|~\/|\/)?(?#Username:Password)  
(?:\w+:\w+@)?(?#Subdomains)(?:(?:[-\w]+\.)+(?#TopLevel Domains)  
(?:com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum|travel|  
[a-z]{2}))(?#Port)(?::[\d]{1,5})?(?#Directories)(?:(?:(?:\/(?:[-\w~!$+|.,=]  
|%[a-f\d]{2})+)+|\/)+|\?|#)?(?#Query)(?:(?:\?(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\d{2}])  
+=?(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)(?:&(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\d{2}])+=?  
(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)*)*(?#Anchor)(?:#(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]  
|%[a-f\d]{2})*)?$
```

Here is another a bit shorter from [An Improved Liberal, Accurate Regex Pattern for Matching URLs](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls)

```
(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.]  
[a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+  
(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

Comment: I like it how SuperUsers (regex-based) highlighting/autolinking fails your examples how bad regex are for finding links :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
(http|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?
```